# How to have static axis values when plotting in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am using the following code:

```
x <-sample(1:100, 10);
y <-sample(1:100, 10);
plot(x,y);
```

but I am trying to create a plot with static values on x, y axis.
The problem is that sometimes x axis for example, is presented with a value range from 0 to 80 on the plot, while others from 20 to 100 depending to the random values inside x.

I would like both x, y, to have a value range from 0 to 100 in the plot in all cases, regardless of the values inside x and y matrices.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what exactly you mean by "value range from 1 to 100", one of the following should do the trick.

In the first one, `plot` by default extends the axis limits by 4% at both ends

In the second one, `xaxs="i"` and `yaxs="i"` are used to suppress this behaviour. (See `?par` for more details.)

```
plot(x,y, xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100))
```

[image]

```
plot(x,y, xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100), xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two functions you can use, `xlim()` and `ylim()` within `plot()` which you can use to manually set your axes.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you mean that `xlim` and `ylim` are arguments to `plot`, or more specifically `plot.default`?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to find out the boundaries - you can either choose some (like 0, 100) or find out the real boundaries with `range` function. Then you will use `xlim` and `ylim` plot options. This is an example of finding the real boundaries with `range`:

```
x1 <-sample(1:100, 10);
y1 <-sample(1:100, 10);
x2 <-sample(1:100, 10);
y2 <-sample(1:100, 10);

par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
range_x <- range(x1, x2); // find the range that spans all the data, for x
range_y <- range(y1, y2); // and for y
plot(x1, y1, xlim = range_x, ylim = range_y);
plot(x2, y2, xlim = range_x, ylim = range_y);
```

Comment: But the OP asks that "I would like both x, y, to have a value range from 0 to 100 in the plot in all cases". This doesn't accomplish that...